# spl-token library failing to fetch rent exemption minumum?

Tags: anchor, spl-token, metaplex, metaplex-js, anchor-test

I'm working with the `@solana/spl-token` lib, and when running `createMint`, I keep getting hit with `TypeError: fetch failed`. I have narrowed this down to the `getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint` function call at the beginning of the function as it is the only one which is likely fetching anything.

What can I do about this?

Comment: If `fetch` isn't working, it sounds like the program is having a lower-level issue accessing the internet. Can you check that your system properly makes any calls to the internet?